# Force server to use all resources for resync

Tags: mdadm, md

I need to resync my RAID and noticed that it isn't a big consumer.
I have booted my system with the Rescue CD and started the resync.

Looking at top it seems that the processes doesn't take much resources.

Can I force the mdadm to use ALL resources for the resync?

```
cat /sys/block/md0/md/sync_speed_m*
200000 (system)
50000 (system)
```

Comment: Assuming this is md0 (modify if not), please paste the output from ``cat /sys/block/md0/md/sync_speed_m*``.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: That's strange. What does ``cat /proc/mdstat`` say?

Comment: I thought the cpu load is a good indicator how fast the resync is. mdstat says 100k K/sec. So everything seems to be okay.

Comment: Yeah that's about what you could expect from a normal SATA disk. Modern CPUs don't sweat much with RAID, so you're not likely to see any significant CPU load. Maybe more with RAID5/6 where there's a lot of work to do in a rebuild, but even then its not likely to be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already using all usable  ressources if you don't use it for anything during the resync. This process is nearly *only* limited by the disk speed on modern systems, so you will see very few other resources being used. If you use a hardware RAID controller, the load to the rest of the system will even be zero, as the RAID controller will do all of the work without any other resources used at all.

Comment: Why do I have a cpu load unter 1 %?

Comment: See me edits for more info.

Comment: Hmm yeah seems like that, it copies with 100k K/sec. So it seems everything okay. I thought there will be more load on the server. :)